# Use awk with two files as a filter

Tags: linux, awk

I was wondering if this could be possible:

I have two files:

file a:

```
100005282       C
100016196       G
100011755       C
100012890       G
100016339       C
100013563       C
100015603       G
100008436       G
100004906       C
```

and file b:

```
rs10904494    100004906 A C
rs11591988    100005282 C T
rs10904561    100008436 T G
rs7906287    100011755 A G
rs9419557    100012890 A G
rs9286070    100013563 T C
rs9419478    100015603 G C
rs11253562   100016196 G T
rs4881551    100016339 C A
```

Based on the numbers in $1 from *file a* and $2 from *file b*, comparing the letters in $2 in *file a* with the same numbers in *file b*, at the end the result must be like this:

```
rs10904494    100004906 A C
rs10904561    100008436 T G
rs7906287    100011755 A G
rs9419557    100012890 A G
rs9286070    100013563 T C
```

Showing only the results that dont match.

Can be possible do this with awk?

Comment: Why is `rs7906287    100011755 A G` included in the output? `file b` has neither `A` or `G` for `100011755`, e.g. `100011755       C` Based on your description, `awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next } a[$2]==$4' filea fileb` is all I get.

Comment: which column in `fileb` are you matching with `filea/$2`?  what code have you tried so far, and what (wrong) output did your code generate?

Comment: Dear Mr David. Thanks a lot. The reason is that in DNA we have 4 nucleotides, The first column of letters in file B are from the reference sequence (those nucleotides from the DNA that we can say is "the standar DNA"), and the second column of letters are those mutations that are common in human populations. The files from file A are ancestral nucleotides, it means that are the original letters that we think that arose first with the first humans and as you can see sometimes are nor the letter from the standar DNA neither the first common mutation. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Mr Markp, the column in fileb is the second with the fisrt in filea. If they match, see if the letter in file a match with the letter in $3 in fileb. If they dont match, print the full raw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble with awk, perhaps using grep would be simpler, e.g.

```
cat file1.txt
100005282   C
100016196   G
100011755   C
100012890   G
100016339   C
100013563   C
100015603   G
100008436   G
100004906   C

cat file2.txt
rs10904494  100004906   A   C
rs11591988  100005282   C   T
rs10904561  100008436   T   G
rs7906287   100011755   A   G
rs9419557   100012890   A   G
rs9286070   100013563   T   C
rs9419478   100015603   G   C
rs11253562  100016196   G   T
rs4881551   100016339   C   A

grep -vFwf file1.txt file2.txt
rs10904494  100004906   A   C
rs10904561  100008436   T   G
rs7906287   100011755   A   G
rs9419557   100012890   A   G
rs9286070   100013563   T   C
```

Otherwise, this should work for your use-case:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==FNR {A[$1,$2]; next} !($2,$3) in A' file1.txt file2.txt
rs10904494  100004906   A   C
rs10904561  100008436   T   G
rs7906287   100011755   A   G
rs9419557   100012890   A   G
rs9286070   100013563   T   C
```

Answer (score 1):

this seems like the logic you're looking for

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2; next} a[$2]!=$3' file1 file2

rs10904494    100004906 A C
rs10904561    100008436 T G
rs7906287    100011755 A G
rs9419557    100012890 A G
rs9286070    100013563 T C
```

match file1 $1 with file2 $2 AND print when file1 $2 != file2 $3